# References for this Lagrange's result?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, math-history

Here is the statement http://www.maths-france.fr/Capes/Capes_2013_M2_Enonce.pdf, page 5.

I was wondering of which Lagrange's theorem they are talking about and if there were references about it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The theorem is stated in item 3.6 there.

Comment: Il s'agit du Théorème 5.23 dans [« Introduction to Analytic Number Theory »](https://books.google.com/books?id=3yoBCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PR1&pg=PA116) de Tom Apostol. Dans ce livre-là, c'est un corollaire du Théorème 5.21, qui est celui que l'auteur appelle « Théorème de Lagrange » (tout comme le font les articles correspondants de Wikipédia en anglais et en italien).

Comment: En fait, ce Théorème 5.21 n'est rien d'autre que l'affirmation selon laquelle un polynôme de degré $n$ sur un corps ne peut avoir plus de $n$ racines, appliquée au cas particulier du corps $Z/pZ$.

Comment: @user49640 Merci donc c'est plutôt un corollaire au final qui vient du théorème de Lagrange sur les équations polynomiales dans les corps finis !

Comment: Oui. Personnellement, je ne connaissais pas cette appellation. Il se pourrait bien que Lagrange ait démontré le 5.21 pour démontrer ensuite le 5.23. Dans ce cas-là, on a le choix d'appeler l'un ou l'autre, voire les deux, théorème de Lagrange.

Comment: @user49640 Possible en tout cas il était inhumain